# Reducing image size in RSS only

Tags: rss, images, feedburner

Is it possible to reduce the image size of WordPress rss feeds parse to feedburner?

Meaning to say I still want to retain the large image size on the original post page but only display the thumbnail or medium sized image when subscribers are reading it via feedburner.

Answer (score 2):

It's very possible, but quite hard to accomplish reliably for all cases (I was working on a plugin for client to do this and more, but sadly the project was never completed).

But if you need this for specific blog that you have control over - then task can be simplified with some constrains - mainly limiting processing to attachments only.

If so:

- filter `the_content_rss`, extract all images with regexp;
- determine attachments IDs for images, see [this question and my answer there](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/turn-a-url-into-an-attachment-post-id) for some helpful code;
- retrieve attachment `img` tag in smaller size and replace currently used version with it.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about thumbnails then yeah, but if you're talking about images inserted in your post then probably not that easy. You'd have to hook to `the_content` and see if the current view is the RSS view, then run a regexp for images and possibly swap the sizes. WordPress has a naming convention for different registered (`add_image_size`) sizes so you shouldn't have much trouble there.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a plugin that does this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/rss-image-resize/

Thanks, @Rarst for getting me on the right path to do this!