# How to get the cropped image from media library?

Tags: images, attachments

i have the url of an image (full size). During the upload it already generates a smaller version (i added this in functions). How can i get this cropped version when i have the full size url?

The Image is not in a post so i can't use post-thumbanil() The image is in a slider on the Homepage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get the attachment ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7094/73) for the image, then get the post meta field `_wp_attachment_metadata` for it. This is a serialized array. The field `sizes` in that array contains all available image sizes.

Pseudo-code:

```
$sizes = array();

$attachment_url  = 'http://examle.com/wp-content-uploads/foo.png';
$attachment_dir  = dirname( $attachment_url );
$attachment_id   = get_attachment_id( $attachment_url );
$attachment_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_metadata', TRUE );

$sizes[] = $attachment_url; // main file

if ( ! empty ( $attachment_meta[ 'sizes' ] ) )
{
    foreach ( $attachment_meta[ 'sizes' ] as $size )
        $sizes[] = "$attachment_dir/" . $size[ 'file' ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have taken the largest part of your code and I have edited it a little. Now it works perfect