# What to do with unattached logos and header uploaded via native wordpress uploader?

Tags: uploads, media-library, header-image

Normally when we sort unattached images, they include logos and header images too. My question is simple. Is there any method to keep header and logos safe from deletion?

Is it possible to attach them to a page (eg logo or header page) automatically when uploaded so that they will not appear unattached in media library.

Comment: How exactly they are implemented?

Comment: Using wordpress custom headers. http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers

Comment: Can you please also specify where the logos are implemented? This seems to be a feature of your theme :)

Comment: Logos are implemented in site header. :D

Comment: Please let me know the name of your current theme so I can have a look :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an ID as `post_parent` to the attachment of the header image via [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) (even though this seems to be a very very hacky way to do it!)

The tricky part is to get the ID out of the attachment URL; fortunately Rarst solved this issue long time ago, so you can manually add [`get_attachment_id()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7094/32946) to your functions.

Next you'll have to assign an ID as `post_parent`; everytime you'll save the header image the selected header image will be attached to this special ID.

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'attach_header_image' );
function attach_header_image() {
  if ( isset( $_POST['default-header'] ) ) :
    $header_image_url = get_header_image();
    $header_image_id = get_attachment_id( $header_image_url ); // function via https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7094/32946
    $args = array(
      'ID' => $header_image_id,
      'post_parent' => 1 // assign header image to this ID
    );
    wp_update_post( $args );
  endif;
}
```

Nevertheless this seems to be a tricky way to solve the issue and it would probably superior to write an exception for the delete function...

**Debugging Infos:**

- echo `get_header_image()` should output the link to the current header image URL (only true if a header image is defined)
- echo `get_attachment_id( $header_image_url )` should output the ID of the attachment page which should be equal to the ID of the attachment page you can see in Media (/wp-admin/post.php?**post=123**&action=edit); make also sure to copy and paste [`get_attachment_id()`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7094/32946) function from Rarst to your functions!
- the if-statement containing `default-header` should check for the `name` of the checked input header field, which will be saved via `$_POST`
  [image]

Comment: Ok, I tested this function for header images, It didn't work. But later I tested it for front-end images just to ensure if something missing or wrong. But It worked perfectly. I think problem is with either `default-header` or `get_header_image`. I'll check into it.

Comment: @Waqas: I added some debugging infos to the answer! Let me know if it works for you! :)

Comment: O snap! error was in my head. I wasn't hitting "Save Changes" button after uploading. :D