# Save attachment ID instead of URL in custom field

Tags: custom-field, attachments, id

I am testing several frameworks (currently Vafpress) to help me creating custom meta boxes. I need to save a lot of attachments with my posts but noticed that the attachment is saved with its full URL, not the ID.

1. There seems to be no "easy" way to get full data (title, desc, date) from an attachment, when I only have the URL, right?
2. Is there any framework that saves ID instead of the URL?
3. Any other suggestions to save attachments, maybe without a custom meta box?

Comment: Did you try to use [`get_attachment_id()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7094/32946) function from Rarst?

Comment: This seems very specific to that particular framework. That would make this question off-topic.

Comment: Have seen this in all tested frameworks/classes

Comment: @suntrop assuming all frameworks/classes do same thing, most probably each do it in different framework specific way. So it's impossible to post an answer that's is good for all.

Comment: OK, I'll try another way to get my things done.

Answer (score 1):

At some point in the process you could do the following:

1. Generate attachment ID from URL, like [here](http://frankiejarrett.com/get-an-attachment-id-by-url-in-wordpress/)
2. Save attachment ID to custom field value using [add_post_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta)
3. Retrieve attachment using custom field value later with [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)