# Is it possible to get feature image url (full-size) from an image url of smaller size?

Tags: images

Supposing that we know nothing except the url of image (smaller size e.g. 150x150)

```
http://xxx.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/test-image-150x150.jpg
```

What is the best way to get its full-size image url from the url above?

or

Just easily remove the prefix "-150x150" ? (I'm not sure if this is proper since i need best practice also.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct :-)

Comment: You can get the ID from the URL by using the method shown [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6645/22534). After you have the ID available you can use it get the information you want.

Comment: @ialocin Thanks for suggestion. However, that seems over-complicated to me ;(

Comment: @MattRoyal Hey, are you really ok with just removing "-150x150" suffix? lol

Comment: @AtthaponJunpun-eak, seeing as though the URL is always appended using that convention, I have never had a problem with it ;-)

Comment: If it is over-complicated really depends on how bad - and at the end in which context - you need it, but that you have to decide yourself of course. Besides that I just suggested it because it might be helpful.

Comment: @ialocin Hey, I have no problem with that since I thank to all recommendations from everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for rezied images in WordPress is constructed in a way that's impossible to direct reverse. Therefore, it's impossible to get the attachment associated with a URL of a resized image with 100% certainty, unless you loop through all attachments and check whether their URL matches the given URL. However, this approach is very slow and resource-intensive.

In any normal WordPress setup, you can rest assured that, given a URL of a resized image, you can retrieve the full image URL by removing the dimensions from the URL. This is, however strange it may seem, best practice.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. This really confirms my thought about removing dimension suffix. Marked as answer though. ;)