# Retrive images from the_content()

Tags: plugins, filters, the-content

I would like to get the images from the_content(), I know I could use a regex to get the images but I wanted to know if there is any other more 'wordpress way' for doing this?

I have this within a plugin and I have a filter

```
 add_filter('the_content', 'myTestContentFunction');
```

Thank you

Comment: If the images you are trying to retrieve were added via the media uploader, a better & more WordPress way of getting the images would be to use the `get_children` function with the `post_type` parameter set to 'attachments'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are essentially three criteria here:

- do images belong to the site (are WP attachments)
- are images attached to this post
- are images used in this post

This has side effects, like:

- images used in post are not necessarily attachments
- post's attachments aren't necessarily used in *that* post

So the only reliable way to produce complete set of images, actually used in specific post's content is indeed to parse the content (after shortcodes like galleries and embeds) for them.

After that you can [try] reverse engineer URLs into WP's attachments, see [Turn a URL into an Attachment / Post ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/turn-a-url-into-an-attachment-post-id/7094#7094) for example.

Comment: I can detect if the images are wp_attachements with ease, then but my problem is to have something out of the box for this.
For e.g.: [gallery ids="10,11,12"], I was unable to find any hook that can give me the ids without me doing a regex or somehing to get the string and then do an explode or something. I don't see this a very good approach to do things, I consider it more of a 'hack'. I like to avoid hacks as much as possible.

Comment: @MariusTalagiu you don't have a "clean" choice here. It's "unreliable" (querying post's attachments), "hack" (parsing content), or nothing.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I have figured as well, but I thought there is something out there that I have missed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [get_attached_media()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attached_media), function. I have linked the above to the Codex.

P.S This is not my own code, straight from the WordPress Codex:

```
<ul>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
           echo '<li>';
           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<p>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );
           echo '</p></li>';
          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

**EDIT**

You could try something like this:

```
function get_attached_images() {
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
$media = get_attached_media( 'image', $post_id );
}
```

Comment: Since this is inside of a plugin I can not do the have_post(). But I have something in mind based on your answer, thank you. I will give it a shot and get back with a reply.