# How do I get attachment_id?

Tags: metabox, attachments

This is trivial, but I can't really find an answer, I've seen some hints like search in database etc., but this is madness.

Basically, I have a metabox with upload button that allows you to upload or pick existing image from Media Library, that's how I get the URL of this image:

```
$my_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_image_metabox', true);
```

Of course I do want exact size of this image to be displayed so I need to use:

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'desired-size');
```

The question is how do I get `attachment_id` of `_my_image_metabox`? I've been searching literally everywhere and there are no sane answers, how is `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` supposed to work if there's not a single line on getting `$attachment_id` in Codex whatsoever? :)

**[updated]**

`var_dump($my_image)` returns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(86) "http://localhost/theme/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/my_image.jpg" }
```

Saving the data is pretty complicated as I use my own metabox generating class, something like this: https://github.com/nyordanov/SmartMetaBox/blob/master/SmartMetaBox.php

How do I inject the proper attachment_id to my_image then? I'd add I have multiple (10) fields like this one and would like every single one to have separate, unique attachment_id.

Comment: The meta box probably does not have an attachment ID associated with it unless you add it, `$my_image` is just a string. Set `get_post_meta` to `false` and debug what it actually returns.

Comment: Please update the question and show us how you _save_ the data. Retrieval should be fairly easy then.

Comment: Thanks, question updated :) I don't need to have an attachment_id here though, I just need to get proper size for the image added to metabox (it is in Media Library so has proper thumbnails), but I think that's the only way (excepting regexp).

Comment: There is [Turn a URL into an Attachment / Post ID](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/6645/22534), which could be helpful. Aside from that, you'd have to explicitly save the the id, like @Wyck said.

Comment: I've been working it out for quite a while and I'm wondering - how can I get the proper ID here?

Comment: if you're inside the loop on a attachment page, a simple `get_the_ID()` will do.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, all those hipercomplex functions can be reduced to one simple command: `attachment_url_to_postid`

You only need to parse the image url to retrieve the attachment id:

```
<?php

   $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $image_url );
   echo $attachment_id;

?>
```

That's all you need.

Comment: This is BY FAR the best answer. The reason being that no other function like url_to_postid or get_page_by_path will return an ID if the the media is attached to a post.

Answer (score 4):

I am too late to answer this question but it will worked.

```
$attachment_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
$url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'desired-size');
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while I was using CMB plugin, I solved adding a custom function to `functions.php` to get the image ID using the image url:

#### functions.php

```
function cmb_get_image_id($image_src) {
    global $wpdb;
    $image = $wpdb->get_col($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE guid='%s';", $image_src )); 
    return $image[0]; //return the image ID
}
```

#### In your theme:

```
$my_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_image_metabox', false);
$attachment_id = cmb_get_image_id($my_image);
wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, 'desired-size');
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do in such cases in that save the id in a hidden input along with the URL.

```
function meta_image_upload() {
    global $post;
    $my_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_image_metabox', true);
    $my_image_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_image_id_metabox', true);

    $out = '<input id="my_image" type="text" name="my_uploaded_image" value="'. $my_image .'">';
    $out .= '<input id="my_image_id" type="hidden" name="my_uploaded_image_id" value="'. $my_image_id .'">';
    $out .= '<button id="my_image_upload">Upload Image</button>';

    echo $out;
}
```

On the upload handler script:

```
attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
    $('#my_image').val(attachment.url);
    $('#my_image_id').val(attachment.id); // Just add this line
```

Then at other callbacks :

```
global $post;
$my_image_id = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_my_image_id_metabox', true);
wp_get_attachment_image_src($my_image_id, 'desired-size');
```

That's just my solution and someone might come up with a better one. However, I found it faster than querying database to fetch the associated attachment id.

Answer (score 0):

All the post meta you're saving is being attached to a post of type attachment, so You can consider  `$post->ID` is the attachment ID.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
$attachment_id = $wpdb->get_var( 
    $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT wposts.ID 
            FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta 
            WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
            AND wpostmeta.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file' 
            AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '%s' 
            AND wposts.post_type = 'attachment'", 
        $url
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it works. Also format your code, it is unreadable