# Get video attachment ID and display length

Tags: attachments, videos

I need to show length of a video attachment.

Video is in media library. I put the video normally, by wp administration.

I am using this code in content.php, inside the loop, after this:

```
 <?php the_content( sprintf(
                __( 'Continue reading %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentythirteen' ),
                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )  ) );
```

I add this code:

```
     $video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );
echo $video_meta['length_formatted'];
```

But i don't know how to get $attachment_id.

I am using twentythirteen theme. Last versione of WP.

Is it possible show length?

Comment: If you can determine the URL, then you can use [`get_attachment_id()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7094/22534) by @Rarst.

Comment: Where are you using this?

Comment: how can i determine URL and then how can i use  get_attachment_id() ?

Comment: I am using that code in content.php, into the loop, after: <?php the_content( sprintf( ... ?>

Comment: what's the context - is it for an attachment page? Or is it for the post parent, where you could have an array of video attachments. Please update your question with all the related info, from the comments.

Comment: i have edited. I hope now is a bit more exhaustive.