# Generating Responsive Background Image Sizes in PHP

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, images, responsive

Im trying to generate responsive background images for my page header, using a modified version of this [gist](https://gist.github.com/joshuadavidnelson/eb4650aa1ee8da9c7d731960e9402e21), but I cant get it to work correctly, and Im not sure if the issue is with `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset`, `wp_calculate_image_sizes` or the loop itself.

Here's my code:

**Responsive Image Size Attributes**

```
function adjust_image_sizes_attr( $sizes, $size ) {
    $width = $size[0];
    if($width >= 1260){
        $sizes = '(max-width:575px) 575px, (max-width:767px) 767px, (max-width:991px) 991px, (max-width:1199px) 1199px, 1260px)';
    }
    elseif($width >= 900){
        $sizes = '(max-width:767px) 100vw, (max-width:991px) 631px, (max-   width:1199px) 839px, 900px)';
    }
    elseif($width >= 600){
        $sizes = '(max-width:767px) 100vw, 600px';
    }
    else{
        $sizes= '(max-width: ' . $width . 'px) 100vw, ' . $width . 'px';
    }

    return $sizes;
}
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_sizes', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\adjust_image_sizes_attr', 10 , 2 );
```

**Generate Responsive Background Image CSS**

```
function gsc_responsive_bg_images($attachment_id, $img_size, $selector)
{
    $img_srcset = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $attachment_id, $img_size );
    $sizes = explode( ", ", $img_srcset );
    $css = '';
    $prev_size = '';
    foreach( $sizes as $size ) {

        // Split up the size string, into an array with [0]=>img_url, [1]=>size
        $split = explode( " ", $size );
        if( !isset( $split[0], $split[1] ) )
            continue;

        $background_css = '.gsc-page-title-bar {
            background-image: url(' . esc_url( $split[0] ) . ')
        }';

        // Grab the previous image size as the min-width and/or add the background css to the main css string
        if( !empty( $prev_size ) ) {
            $css .= '@media only screen and (min-width: ' . $prev_size . ') {';
            $css .= $background_css;
            $css .= "}\n";
        } else {
            $css .= $background_css;
        }

        // Set the current image size as the "previous image" size, for use with media queries
        $prev_size = str_replace( "w", "px", $split[1] );
    }
    return $css;
}
```

**My Output: (in shorthand) **
    default.jpg (original dimensions: 1170w)

```
@min-width: 1170px -> 768w.jpg
@min-width: 768px -> 120w.jpg
@min-width: 120px -> 500w.jpg
@min-width: 500px -> 700w.jpg
@min-width: 700px -> 200w.jpg
@min-width: 400px -> 600w.jpg
@min-width: 600px -> 800w.jpg
```

I was expecting

Seeing this, Im left with a bunch of questions:

1. Why is this the CSS code thats being returned? Shouldnt it be the smallest size being returned at the default breakpoint and the largest size at `@min-width:1170px`? Why does `@min-width: 768px -> 120w.jpg` , and `@min-width: 700px -> 200w.jpg`?
2. Why are these the srcset images that are being generated? Shouldn't they be 900px, 767px, 839px, 631px?

Any and all help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code, but I recently spent a few hours hacking something together to solve the same issue -- making background images set via the WordPress customizer load responsively.  Feel free to use / modify the code below to your needs, and send any questions my way.  I'm not a PHP expert by any measure, however.

#### *3 things to note about the code below:*

1. I'm assuming you have already set up your customizer code, or are ok with just adding this CSS somewhere else via an echo / filter.
2. This code uses a [function](https://wpscholar.com/blog/get-attachment-id-from-wp-image-url/) to get an attachment's ID based on its URL that was created by Micah Wood, who in turn credits this [function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/turn-a-url-into-an-attachment-post-id/7094#7094) developed by Andrey Savchenko (a.k.a. “Rarst”).  I've included it as the second function below, but be sure to check out both links for more info.
3. I've only targeted -webkit- with the pixel density, if you want to add other vendor prefixes (eg: -o-), that could be done.

## Responsive Customizer Backgrounds

```
    /**
     * Create CSS Rules for Responsive BGs set via the Wordpress Customizer.
     *
     * @uses get_attachment_id()            Gets attachment id from $img_url
     * @link https://wpscholar.com/blog/get-attachment-id-from-wp-image-url/
     *
     * @param string $selector              The css selector set via customizer
     * @param string $img_url               The attachment url set via customizer
     *
     * @return string $responsive_css       CSS rules on success, 0 on failure
     */

    function responsive_customizer_bgs($selector='', $img_url='') {

      // return var
      $responsive_css = 0;

      // get attachment id based on url (uses helper func)
      $image_id = get_attachment_id( $img_url );

      // get the src string from WP
      $srcset_string = wp_get_attachment_image_srcset( $image_id, 'full' );

      // parse srcset string into [url][int][width-or-pixel-density]
      preg_match_all(
        "/([^\s]*)\s(\d*)([w|x])/",
        $srcset_string,
        $srcset_matches,
        PREG_SET_ORDER
      );

      // check if regex match was successful
      if( is_array($srcset_matches) ) {

          // cast int string into integer
          for ($i=0; $i < count($srcset_matches); $i++) {
              $srcset_matches[$i][2] = (int) $srcset_matches[$i][2];
          }

          // sort array of sizes by integer
          usort($srcset_matches, function($a, $b) {
            return $a[2] >= $b[2] ? -1 : 1;
          });

          // indexed loop to walk multi-dimensional array returned by regex
          for ($i=0; $i < count($srcset_matches); $i++) {
              // set media query statement based pixel size or pixel density
              if ($srcset_matches[$i][3] === 'w') {
                  $media_query_match = 'max-width: ' . $srcset_matches[$i][2] . 'px';
              } else if ($srcset_matches[$i][3] === 'x') {
                  $media_query_match = '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: ' . $srcset_matches[$i][2];
              }

              // create css rules and add to return string
              $responsive_css .= PHP_EOL
                . '@media only screen and (' . $media_query_match . ') {' . PHP_EOL
                . '  ' . $selector . ' {' . PHP_EOL
                . '    background-image: url(' . $srcset_matches[$i][1] . ');' . PHP_EOL
                . '  }' . PHP_EOL
                . '}';

          }

          // return that beautiful responsiveness
          return $responsive_css;

      }

    }
```

## Get Attachment ID Via URL

```
    /**
     * Get an attachment ID given a URL.
     * 
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return int Attachment ID on success, 0 on failure
     */
    function get_attachment_id( $url ) {
        $attachment_id = 0;
        $dir = wp_upload_dir();
        if ( false !== strpos( $url, $dir['baseurl'] . '/' ) ) { // Is URL in uploads directory?
            $file = basename( $url );
            $query_args = array(
                'post_type'   => 'attachment',
                'post_status' => 'inherit',
                'fields'      => 'ids',
                'meta_query'  => array(
                    array(
                        'value'   => $file,
                        'compare' => 'LIKE',
                        'key'     => '_wp_attachment_metadata',
                    ),
                )
            );
            $query = new WP_Query( $query_args );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                foreach ( $query->posts as $post_id ) {
                    $meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $post_id );
                    $original_file       = basename( $meta['file'] );
                    $cropped_image_files = wp_list_pluck( $meta['sizes'], 'file' );
                    if ( $original_file === $file || in_array( $file, $cropped_image_files ) ) {
                        $attachment_id = $post_id;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $attachment_id;
    }
```