# Set featured image using URL with wp rest api

Tags: rest-api

I'm using wordpress REST API for sending posts. I uploaded the media already on the wordpress and i have the urls, now I want while sending the post request for creating a post, i could give it the featured image url like other fields easily.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

When you [create](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post) or [update a post](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#update-a-post), you can pass a `featured_media` argument in the `POST` data containing the media file's post ID. (It appears you need to have the media item's post ID, not the URL, for this to work.)

Comment: Is there anyway to get the id of the media by its url in wordpress?

Comment: @Amirition https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6645/turn-a-url-into-an-attachment-post-id

Comment: @pat-j Since I cant pass the url with the request, do I have to register a custom endpoint for this or there is a way for sending custom parameters to this route ?

Comment: You might have to make a custom endpoint that returns the attachment's ID, using [`attachment_url_to_postid()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/attachment_url_to_postid/), on the REST API server.